# reverse of epsilon delta criterion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my first language and I'm having this class in german, but tried translating my question because this way I'll get help faster.

The so-called $\epsilon \delta$ criterion (or the version we learned) goes as follows: If a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that the following applies: $|x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Now my question is: With a given function, what would be the formula to get $\delta$ in relation (I hope that's formulated somewhat correct) to $x_0$ and $\epsilon$?

If you need an example function: $f(x) = -11 x^2 + 13 x + 3$

Comment: You need $x_0$... Let $x_0=0$; then $f(x_0)=3$. Check that the function is continuous in $x_0=0$.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is: You have a function, and are supposed to create a formula that gives you $\delta$ for any $x_0$ and $\epsilon$ you input.

Comment: You mean a *general* formula, in terms of $f(x), \varepsilon, $ and $x_0$ ? Interesting question, but i doubt it can be done, because for example, the function: $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational; $-x$ if $x$ is irrational, is continuous at $x=0$, but I doubt a *formula* will find us what $\delta$ is: we would need to *inspect* the function from a human perspective.

Comment: Let $f(x)= 13x+3$; then $f(0)=3$. Thus the condition will be: $|x| < \delta \to |13x|< \epsilon$, that means that $\delta$ is computed from $\dfrac {\epsilon}{13}$

Comment: In my opinion, this is a complicated question with no easy answers.  That is, each (similar) problem will involve a different *relationship* between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  The best suggestion that I can make is to find a book/class/teacher that exposes you to a lot of worked examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. In general there is no formula for $\delta$ because it depends on whatever function $f$ and point $x_0$ you are working with. Sometimes $\delta$ might even be independent of $\epsilon$ (for example if $f$ is constant).

To find $\delta$ it usually helps to analyze $f$ and perhaps simplify $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ in the concrete case to try and find a $\delta$ that works. This can be done for example by "solving" the resulting inequality $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $x-x_0$ which gives you $\delta$.

Example:

Lets pick $f(x)= x^2 +2x +5$ and $x_0 =0$. Then we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |x^2 +2x|$. Note that in this case the condition $|x-x_0| < \delta$ gives $|x|<\delta$ which simplifies the problem a bit.
Solving $x^2 + 2x = \epsilon$ for $x$ gives $-1 + \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$.
If we pick $\delta := -1 + \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$ then
$$|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x^2 +2x| \leq x^2 + 2|x| < \epsilon$$
where the last inequality follows if you plug in $\delta$ for x and simplify.

Now note that this "solving" does not always work and is not really formally sound as I am sort of ignoring the absolute values in some cases. However it is a good trick that helps you find a $\delta$ which you can then properly justify by showing why that $\delta$ works as I did in the last equation.

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what I'm supposed to do. Could you give an example of how that would work with a quadratic function like the one I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @RalphBear I added an example to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$ for $\delta$.

Let $f^{-1}(S)$ where $S$ is a set denote the set of all $x$ that map to a value in $S$ by $f$:

$$f^{-1}(S)=\{x:f(x)\in S\}.$$

Now let
$$S:=(f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon),\\ x_-:=\inf_{x\ne x_0}(f^{-1}(S)),\\x_+:=\sup_{x\ne x_0}(f^{-1}(S)).$$

If these values exist, then

$$\delta=\min(x_0-x_-,x_+-x_0)$$ is a solution.

The expanded formula is

$$\delta=\min(x_0-\inf_{x\ne x_0}(f^{-1}((f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon))),\sup_{x\ne x_0}(f^{-1}((f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon)))-x_0).$$

---

Note that there is a very interesting case, when $f$ is invertible, as the formula reduces to

$$\delta=\min(x_0-f^{-1}(f(x_0)-\epsilon),f^{-1}(f(x_0)+\epsilon)-x_0)$$ if $f$ is growing, or
$$\delta=\min(x_0-f^{-1}(f(x_0)+\epsilon),f^{-1}(f(x_0)-\epsilon)-x_0)$$ otherwise. It suffices to evaluate the inverse at two points.

Comment: Even if this is correct, I don't think it is really *helpful*, because you've just shifted the problem from "finding delta" to "finding the inf and sup" of those sets.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Take for counterexample $f:\left[-π, \frac{3π}{2}\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)= \sin x$ and at $x_0=0$, your $S=(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for a fixed $\epsilon >0$ and thus for a sufficiently small $r>0$, $f^{-1}(S)=[-π,-π+r)\cup (-r,r) \cup (π-r, π+r)$ and so $x_{-}=-π$ and $x_{+}=π+r$ and hence your $\delta = \min \left[π,π+r \right] =π$ which does not ensure $\left|f(x)-0\right| < \epsilon \ \blacksquare$ \,

Comment: @AdamRubinson: the special case, which is very frequent, is completely *helpful*. And the general formula has the merit of being *constructive*, and gives the largest bound.

Comment: @Ibrahim: you are quite right, I knew that this inversion issue could raise issues. I'll try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a *general* formula, in terms of $f(x), \varepsilon, $ and $x_0$ ? Interesting question, but i doubt it can be done, because for example, the function: $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational; $-x$ if $x$ is irrational, is continuous at $x=0$, but I doubt a *formula* will find us what $\delta$ is: we would need to *inspect* the function from a human perspective. And of course you can come up with (a lot) more complicated examples than this one, where the function is still continuous at $x_0.$

Comment: There *is* a general formula, see my answer.